# Updating value between open(live) forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a main form which allows opening another forms (at this moment up to 3 form).

I am using following code to open a form from main form:

```
public partial class network : Form
{
    p1 _p1 = new p1();
    p2 _p2 = new p2();
    public network()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Phone1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _p1.Show();
        //Phone1off.Visible = true;
        //networklog.Items.Add("Phone 1 added");
    }
```

above code working fine at the moment.

Now, the problem is when let's say I have opened two forms from main form and have type something in the child form1 then want to display it in child form2. I am unable to do it.

at this moment I have coded as below to achieve this:

```
public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }  
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p2 _p2 = new p2();
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Text = "Calling Phone 2";

        _p2.TextBoxValue = "Phone 1 Calling";

    }
```

also for your information all my child forms will have same layout. so I am inheriting all from 1 design (say form1: form2)

I will appreciate your response

Comment: Your [tag:visual-studio] tag is not relevant. The IDE you use has no effect on this problem, you could write your code in notepad and compile it from the command line and still have the same issue. Please only include relevant tags, read the description of the tag for information.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ef2xyb33(v=vs.110).aspx) to have a Model (a simple class, List or Datatable) being watched by multiple controls.

#### Model

First have a class that will act as the model:

```
public class PhoneModel
{
    public string SomePhone { get; set; }
}
```

Compile this so the designer can find that class when you add ...

#### BindingSource

... to the designer of your Network Form:
[image: bindingsource]

Set the `DataSource` property to an object and choose the `PhoneModel` class.
Set the `Modifiers` property to `Protected`

Do the same for your base class called `P`.

On the `TextBox` select in the properties the `DataBinsdings settings`:

[image: databindings per control]

#### Subclassed form handling

I'm not sure why have two different classes but let's keep that as a fact.

Add an constructor to each of your classes that will accept the `BindingSource` instance from the caller. We use that instance to update the per form BindingSource.

```
public class P1 : P
{
    public P1(BindingSource bs):base()
    {
        base.bindingSource1.DataSource = bs.DataSource;
    }
}
```

Do this for every form you have that needs to synchronize its values

#### Wire your Network form to the P1 and P2 instances

In the click events of your buttons on the Network form start P1 or P2 by providing the `BindingSource` in the constructor:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new P1(this.bindingSource1).Show();
}
```

And have your model instantiated, I used the Form_Load event to do that.

```
private void Network_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.bindingSource1.DataSource = new PhoneModel { SomePhone = "foo" };
}
```

That is all there is. When you enter values in one of the TextBoxes all values on all open forms will get updated due to the BindindingSource that updates all controls that it is bounded to as can be seen in this demo:

[image: demo of multiple fields being updated on change]

Comment: thanks for that, but I was expecting something simpler

Comment: All I want is, let say I have two live form. when user type something on textbox on form1 (say p1) and press call p2 (a button), p2(form 2) textbox should be updated with text in p1 form that user typed. Hope it is much clear now.

Comment: still working on it, let you know. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using .showDialog() instead of .show(). This way, the data in _p2 doesn't disappear when _p2 closes. You'll still be able to access the data from _p2 in _p1. Before you call .showDialog(), you can set the values of the variables of _p2 using the data from _p1. Then, when you do finally call .showDialog(), it will display all the data you set earlier.