# opening a form with a data inside it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 `Form`s: `frmLOGIN`, `frmREGISTER` & `frmACCOUNTS`

`frmLOGIN` has two buttons `BtnRegister` and `BtnLogin`, when I press `BtnRegister`  it opens up `frmREGISTER`.

`frmREGISTER` has 1 button `BtnAddAcc`, `BtnAddAcc` is used to add a rows to `datagridview`(datagridview inside `frmACCOUNTS`)

`frmACCOUNTS` has only 1 `datagridview` inside it, nothing else

`BtnRegister` code (inside `frmLOGIN`)

```
   frmREGISTER frm = new frmREGISTER();
   frm.Show();
   this.Hide();
```

`BtnAddAcc` code (inside `frmREGISTER`)

```
frmACCOUNTS acc = new frmACCOUNTS
acc.datagridview.Rows.Add(userID,ln,fn,Dateofbirth,address,contactnumber,username,password);
```

### PROBLEM

When I register a user, using the code above, **works**, when I try to add code like `acc.Show();` to open the form and see if it adds the row to the `datagridview`, and yes it really adds a row. Now when I get back to the login form and press `BtnLogin` to open up the `frmACCOUNTS` the datagridview rows are **GONE**

Reference

[image]

Comment: "Reference" image link is very informational about the problem

Comment: You need to keep a single datasource for all your records. I have an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920102/update-gridview-column-values-from-another-form-in-c-sharp-winform/32921060#32921060) that shows how that can be done. Another example of mine is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893575/updating-value-between-openlive-forms/31893967#31893967).

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question

Answer is that you need to create a CLASS

```
Class Controller
{
 public static frmLOGIN log = new frmLOGIN();
 public static frmREGISTER reg = new frmREGISTER();
 public static frmACCOUNTS acc = new frmACCOUNTS();

 public static void FormOpen(string form_name)
 {
    if(form_name == "accounts")
     {
        acc.Show();
     }
    else if (form_name == "register")
     {
       reg.Show();
     }
    else if (form_name == "login")
     {
       log.Show();
     }
 }
}
```

now to use this. you do not need to call the form again inside the other forms you just need to call the class and and the call the form there.

example

let's say, I want to show **login form**
so I will call

```
Controller.FormOpen("login");
```

let's say I want to use the **datagridview** inside the **Accounts form**
and put it inside a new variable

```
Datagridview DGV = Controller.acc.Datagridview1
```

now you can use the `datagridview` inside the accounts form as `DGV`

**Conclusion**

call the form inside a class so when other forms wants to call/use another form they will be calling the same forms and not making a `new` one