# Strategies to update multiple UI controls in a synchronous fashion

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a bunch of custom UI controls that I've written for an industrial application. The software is written in C# using WinForms.

Lets say that all UI controls are on a single form, and that the UI controls display various pieces of information in text and graphical format. The information is queried serially from a data-source.

At the moment, the way I'm updating individual controls is by invalidation of their paint regions via a system timer. It works well, but I would like to move to a design where every control always displays information that is consistent with what other controls are displaying. I.e. all controls should update simultaneously and/or pause their re-paints to let other controls 'catch up'.

To avoid reinventing the wheel here, is there an established way to do this? (Either by means of the UI framework or by a simple design change) Needless to say, I am new to WinForms development :)

Comment: Updating should be instantaneous. Unless you are computing stuff before setting the value of the control. If that is the case you should think into computing everything (async if possible) and once all the data is computed send that to a method that set each value to the appropriate control.

Comment: I am not transforming the data, but the drawing of the controls requires a modest amount of computation (complicated graphs). It is not a design requirement for the controls to be real-time, just that all of them should display data that is from the same update time-slice at all times.

Comment: Use a viewmodel that implement INotifyProperyChanged and then bind the instance of that viewmodel by means of a BindingSource, something like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920102/update-gridview-column-values-from-another-form-in-c-sharp-winform/32921060#32921060) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893575/updating-value-between-openlive-forms/31893967#31893967)

Comment: It's not clear why you need a timer and why some controls are *left behind* in the update. It also depends on how deep you are willing to go in the re-design. It looks like a MVVM pattern. But it could be overkill and difficult in a WinForms app. See this evolution of MVVM: [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui). Also, as @rene pointed out, a clever implementation of [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.7.2) (it doesn't require a MVVM pattern) could solve the problem.

Comment: @Jimi Some controls are just a textbox/label or a simple guage and those update instantly. Some controls require more computation (circular charts with multiple trend lines, for e.g.) Ofcource, it doesn't help that this is a legacy app and the computer that I have to make it work with isn't the latest. But anyway, getting back on topic, I think I have gotten some ideas now that I've read some more about data binding and a few other things. Thanks guys!